# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with REST-assured 3.0.0 and Java 11 (not observed with Java 8)

Tags: java, gradle, rest-assured

Here's what my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "0.7.0"
    id 'application'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.0'
}

task runTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites 'src/test/testng.xml'
    }
}
```

Here's what my `testng.xml` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="my-test-suite">
    <test name="myTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.SomeTests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testVerifySomething"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error originates from the `SomeTests` class at the line where there is a call to a static method from another class `SomeUtils` from another package `utils`.

Here's the full trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at io.restassured.config.ObjectMapperConfig.<init>(ObjectMapperConfig.java:49)
    at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:420)
    at utils.SomeUtils.createUser(SomeUtils.java:13)
    at tests.SomeTests.createUser(SomeTests.java:63)
    at tests.SomeTests.testCreateUsers(SomeTests.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:131)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:768)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1052)
    ... 56 more
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
build.gradle
src
--test
----java
------tests
        SomeTests
------utils
        SomeUtils
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Add `runtime files('src/test/java/utils')` inside the `dependencies` section of my build.gradle.
2. Add `compile files('src/test/java/utils')` inside the `dependencies` section of my build.gradle.
3. Add both 1 & 2 inside the `dependencies` section of my build.gradle.

**EDIT:** After some trial and errors, it seems the Java version is the cause here since the issue is seen with Java 11 and not with Java 8. I verified this behaviour on multiple machines just to ensure there's nothing specific on my machine.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. it might help someone to isolate the issue.

Comment: Updated. Actually, it does not show many details on the CI console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the complete error trace, it seems the error is originating from the REST-assured library's code. And upgrading `io.rest-assured` dependency from 3.0.0 to 4.0.0 has helped overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified exactly which class is not found!
Complete stackstrace will help.

Nevertheless, as you mentioned it worked on jdk8 which means there is high probability you are using/depending on some class which is removed after jdk9 like jaxb, javax etc.

If that is the case, you have couple of options here:

- run your app/test with following `jvmopts` setting `--add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.activation` or create `.jvmopts` file with above line at root directory of your project
- add explicit dependency in you build based on which class is missing

Comment: My bad! I did not add the full trace in the question which I've done now. It seems the issue is originating from the REST-assured library. Looking into this further.

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing the version of the rest assured dependency . from 3.0.0 to 4.1.2

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

it will help

Answer (score 0):

It is because the JAXB library (Java Architecture for XML Binding) is missing in the classpath. JAXB is included in Java SE 10 or older, but it is removed from Java SE from Java 11 or newer –moved to Java EE under Jakarta EE project.
That means if you encounter JAXBException error, it’s very much likely that you are using Java 11 or newer for your project. So to fix this error, you have to options:

1. Use older Java versions like JDK 8, 9, or 10 which still include the JAXB library by default. Or:
2. Specify an additional dependency in your project’s pom.xml file as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In case you don’t use Maven
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0

Answer (score -1):

The "root" of your code files ie test files in this case should be `src/test/java`. So, you could try adding `compile files('src/test/java') to your`testClasspath` variable.

Comment: That does not seem to help.